# "Unclosed counted closure" with String.matches using unknown strings

Tags: java

The following code

```
String str1, str2;

// code that assigns contents to str1 and str2

if (!str1.matches(str2)) something=false;
```

produces an "Unclosed counted closure" exception if str2 contains a special character such as {.  How can I avoid this happening if I do not know what will be the contents of str2 or str1?  Is it possible to escape characters in an unknown string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `String.matches(String)` method expects a regex as argument. It checks if your str1 matches the given regex. You probably want to use the `String.equals(Object)` method. It checks if the content of the two strings is equal.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of your string has a special character. Make sure to escape the special chars with \

Also if you just want to compare the String use .equals